# Bash: #: command not found

Tags: bash, bashrc

I just moved to Arch Linux with KDE a week ago. Everything worked well until I installed `ibus-unikey` and `ibus-qt`, after that, whenever I open `konsole`, this error appears:

```
bash: #: command not found
```

I doubt that `#` is a usual command because when I type it in `konsole`, nothing happens. But when I run `pacman -Ss #`, a ton of things appear.

**My question:** what is the `#` command and what should I do to fix this error?

Here are my `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and `PATH`

```
$ cat .bashrc
   #
   # ~/.bashrc
   #

   # If not running interactively, don't do anything
   [[ $- != *i* ]] && return
$ cat .bash_profile
   #
   # ~/.bash_profile
   #

   [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc


   alias ls='ls --color=auto'
   PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '


$ echo $PATH
   /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

**Addition 1:** As @terdon suggest, I run

```
$ grep -FH '\#' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2>/dev/null
```

and receive nothing. But the later command give me

```
$ grep -P '(^|\s+)(\.|source) .' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2>/dev/null
   /home/thuyenarc/.bash_profile:[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
   /etc/bash.bashrc:[ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion   ] && . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
   /etc/profile:           test -r "$profile" && . "$profile"
   /etc/profile:   . /etc/bash.bashrc
   /etc/profile.d/locale.sh:    . "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/locale.conf"
   /etc/profile.d/locale.sh:    . "$HOME/.config/locale.conf"
   /etc/profile.d/locale.sh:    . /etc/locale.conf
```

**Addition 2:** I tried renaming the `.bashrc` file, then opened `konsole`, the error had gone. I suspect that the errors must come from `.bashrc`. Any ideas?

Comment: The only way i could think youd get that error is if there was an escaped `#` somewhere.

Comment: In most shells, an unescaped `#`, at the start of a new token (ie, after whitespace), starts a comment until the end of the line. So this is definitely odd.  The only thing I can think of is that `paman -Ss #` is trying to execute a command `#`; but that would be done outside of the shell. The other possibility is that something tampered with IFS.

Comment: @Otheus no, `pacman -Ss #` just runs `pacman -Ss`. The `#` is treated as a comment and is ignored.

Comment: @terdon assuming he's running that from a shell.

Comment: @Otheus how else would the OP run `pacman -Ss #`? It has to be run from a shell.

Comment: To the OP: I don't see an arch-linux package named `ibus-qt4`. I see one named `ibus-qt`, which depends on `qt4`.  Neither of the ibus packages contain a file that has anything to do with bash. However, possibly one of the dependencies does.

Comment: @terdon maybe as an argument to Konsole. Gnome's terminal passes arguments from `-e` parameter [directly to exec](http://superuser.com/a/198022/437093) rather than via the shell.

Comment: @Otheus Thank you for pointing out my typos, the package is `ibus-qt`, not `ibus-qt4`.

Comment: After posting output from `grep -P ... source`, you found `"$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/locale.conf"`, `"$HOME/.config/locale.conf"`, and `/etc/locale.conf`.  Now grep those for `#` as you did with the first command.

Comment: Try running as `env SHELLOPTS=xtrace PS4='${BASH_SOURCE[*]}:$LINENO: ' konsole` to see where that error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means that you have an escaped `#` (this means `\#`) in one of bash's initialization files. Since it doesn't seem to be in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, it has to be in one of the other files bash reads when it is loaded. To be sure, just search through all of them<sup>1</sup>:

```
grep -FH '\#' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login \
              ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \
              /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2>/dev/null
```

That should show you that one of the files listed above contains a `\#`. Edit the file, remove it and everything should work.

If the command doesn't return any output, that means that one of those files is sourcing another—non-standard—file, and that's the file that has the error. If this is the case, please edit your question and add the output of this command:

```
grep -P '(^|\s+)(\.|source) .' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login \
                              ~/.bash_aliases  /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \
                              /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2>/dev/null
```

That should print all instances of sourcing another file and should point us in the right direction.

More generally, `#` is not a command, it is a comment. Anything after it is simply ignored by `bash`. So, when you run `pacman -Ss #`, you are actually running `pacman -Ss` alone which is why you get so many results.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Some of those files are irrelevant here. For example, `~/.profile` is ignored if `~/.bash_profile` exists and `/etc/profile` won't be read when you open a new terminal, but you may as well search through all of them just in case.</sub>

Comment: It's a good list, but setting `PS4='$0 : '` at the top of `.profile` or `...rc` and starting up w/ `-x` might be more direct. Interactive shells, though, dont interpret inline comments by default, I think, and so if some input comes via stdin it could happen without being escaped if it wasnt the first on a line. whats that file that readline looks at for key programming? returns in some files rather than newlines might make something like that happen, maybe.

Comment: @mikeserv yes, setting `PS4` that way is a good trick (and probably deserves its own answer) but that produces (or can produce) a _lot_ of output. I think it's far more likely that one of the startup files has a malformed line. If the OP tries this and it turns out not to be the case, we can investigate further. As for interactive shells, bash at least, does interpret comments. Try `echo foo #bar`. Same for non-interactive, try `printf 'echo foo # bar' | bash`. The file you're thinking of is probably `~/.inputrc` but adding a `\#` (or `#`) there doesn't produce the error.

Comment: i only piped up at all because of the mention of that ibus thing - its some kind of language/keyboard switcher or whatever. i can imagine a hasty edit somewhere could lodge a few weird, unprintable *(or even incomplete)* characters in and among the more standard kinds, and those things can screw with a shells idea of an input line. is it a configurable thing then? the inline comment deal? i know read about it once in man bash...

Comment: my bad: *interactive* comments: In a non-interactive shell, or an interactive shell in which the interactive_comments option to the `shopt` builtin is enabled *(see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below)*, a word beginning with `#` causes that word and all  remaining  characters on that line to be ignored. An interactive shell without the *interactive_comments* option enabled does  not  allow comments.  The  *interactive_comments* option is on by default in interactive shells.

Comment: Indeed. @mikeserv I dont want to steal your answer. If one does `shopt -u interactive_comments`, Then entering `#` may result in `# command not found`

Comment: @Otheus - you'd better not steal it! how then would i feed my kids!??

Comment: @mikeserv with byte-sized snacks, of course.

Comment: @Otheus  - that was just tongue-in-cheek encouragement to please do share information gained any way you might if you feel its worth sharing. i dont discuss this stuff on the internet because i wanna keep it to myself. i think youre on to something, and i only hit upon it by accident. you tested it - if you write it up, ill vote for it.

Comment: @terdon have a look at latest diagnostic fubar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259829/bash-command-not-found/259863?noredirect=1#comment450692_259863

Answer (score 2):

It may be that somehow the BASH-shell-option `interactive_comments` was disabled. You can replicate the behavior with:

```
~ $ shopt -u interactive_comments
~ $ # 
# command not found
~ $
```

You can determine if it's on or off :

```
$ shopt interactive_comments
```

If the output is "on", then this is *not* the source of your problem. If it is "off", then you should grep your files (/u/tedron's answer) to look for where this is being set.

Comment: When I run `shopt interactive_comments`, the result is   `interactive_comments    on`.

Comment: ^bummer. i thought it was right. @MặcNguyênĐặng - do you get anything out of `echo exit | bash -ix 2>&1 | grep comment`? Another test I'd be curious to know the results of is: `echo exit | PS4='$0 : $LINENO : ' bash -ix 2>&1 | grep '[^[:print:]]'`

Comment: @mikeserv I recieve nothing. Could you explain what it's mean?

Comment: @MặcNguyênĐặng - yeah, it was just a quick look through your init files for some change to that `shopt` thing.

Comment: @MặcNguyênĐặng - oh... but the `'[^[:print:]]` thing wont work, cause `bash` sanitizes non-printables in xtrace output... if you would try...  `echo exit | PS4='$0 : $LINENO : $BASH_COMMAND : ' bash -ix 2>&1 | grep '[^[:print:]]'` it might work better.

Comment: @mikeserv I try `echo exit | PS4='$0 : $LINENO : $BASH_COMMAND : ' bash -ix 2>&1 | grep '[^[:print:]]'` and get just `exit`.

Comment: @MặcNguyênĐặng - yeah - that's your prompt - but that wouldn't. here leave off the `grep` and you can just see what your shell does when you start it up: `echo exit | PS4='$BASH_SOURCE : $LINENO : $BASH_COMMAND + ' bash -lix `

Comment: @mikeserv I get a long result that I can't post here. Can you give me some ideas to find out the error, or do you need some information? There is a line `bash: #: command not found`, and above it are
`+++ [[ -r /home/thuyenarc/.bash_completion ]]`
`+++ unset -f have`
`+++ unset have`
`+++ set +v`
`+++ unset BASH_COMPLETION_ORIGINAL_V_VALUE`
`+ unset TERMCAP`
`+ unset MANPATH`
`+ [[ -f /home/thuyenarc/.bashrc ]]`
`+ . /home/thuyenarc/.bashrc`
`++ #`

Comment: @MặcNguyênĐặng 0 That's what you're looking for. Must be in that `have` function. Something in your programmable completions.

Comment: @MặcNguyênĐặng let's take this to chat?

Comment: @mikeserv Could you tell me how to find `have` function, I tried `which`, `whereis` but got nothing. I also reinstall `bash-completion` but the error is still there.

Comment: @Otheus Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to chat in SE.

Comment: Try this: `cd $HOME; touch empty.sh; export ENV=$HOME/empty.sh; konsole`  This should force the shell to be run without any initialization scripts.

Comment: @Otheus I run the commands, a new konsole window appears with the same error.

Comment: OK, try `konsole -e /bin/sh`

Comment: A second `konsole` windows appears with `sh-4.3$`. In the first window: `$ konsole -e /bin/sh`
`QCoreApplication::arguments: Please instantiate the QApplication object first`
`QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.` So what does it mean?

Comment: It tells me the QDBus people did something architecturally very stupid. And then they managed to introduce a bug. :(   What are the chances you can rebuild your archilinux environment in a VM (say, using VirtualBox)?

Comment: xref with https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347008 and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1242207 . I think KDE's konsole requires a library which requires an environment variable of some sort, and that variable is set in the same file which causes your original problem.

Comment: @MặcNguyênĐặng (and Otheus) if renaming `.bashrc` fixes it and there is i) no `\#` in `.bashrc` and ii) the only file it sources is `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, it seems likely that the error is in the `bash_completion` file. Could be that a bad update modified it and inserted an `\#`. I might have missed something in the comments, but have you tried `grep -F '\#'  /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`?

Comment: And if what terdon said doesn't work, (1) post this on https://bugs.kde.org/ and be sure to follow up in both places (2) systematically (one by one, testing each time) remove each startup script and initialization file -- you can confirm with `strace -e open konsole` what's being opened. Obviously, you'll need a backup or use LVM snapshots so you can quickly restore.

Comment: @terdon I tried `grep -F '\#' /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` and find out a `\#`. However, after I deleted it, the error still occurs.

Comment: @MặcNguyênĐặng ah, good. And does running the grep again show that it's been removed? Perhaps something adds it again. If not, try logging out and logging back in again.

Comment: @terdon I tried logging out and and logging back, checked if `\#` is removed, but nothing changes.

Comment: @MặcNguyênĐặng so, is it removed or has it been added again?

Comment: @terdon it is removed.

Comment: I found something on this [page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=189806). Using hex editor, the file `~/.bashrc` is different from `/usr/skel/.bashrc` although they have the same content when I open by `nano`!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had is that before the `#` in the `.bashrc` file there seem to have been some invisible characters, or the `#` character looked like `#` but wasn't `#`. When executing `source .bashrc` I got the error. When I copied the content of the file using an editor (I used Emacs) to a new file `tmp` and executed `source tmp` there was no error. So I replaced the file `.bashrc` by `tmp` (`mv tmp .bashrc`) and the problem was solved.

What seems to have happened is that on the system I was using the only editor apart from `vi` was LibreOffice, and I had no permission to install software on it. So I used LibreOffice to adapt the `.bashrc` file. That seems to have added some special characters to the file or modified the character `#`.

Answer (score -1):

Bit late to the party but for me solution was downloading the sample bashrc from the web and then pasting my bashrc's contains to the downloaded one because I used a text editing program(Libre Office Writer) that changed the formatting.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you consider adding some more explanation - e.g. what text editing program you used, and how that changed the formatting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).